# Keep audio-play while sleeping

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I have an `iOS` app using `AVFoundation` and playing audio contents.
Once launched I want it to keep playing, even in the background, until I stop it.
But now as soon as the device goes to sleep or I put the app in the background, it stops playing. How can I fix this and get the behavior I wish.

Here is the kind of code I am using in the app:

```
    var soundSession:AVAudioSession!, audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    .....
    soundSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    .....
    do {try soundSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
        try soundSession.setActive(true)
        if audioPlayer == nil {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url,
                                            fileTypeHint: fileTypHint)
            guard let _ = audioPlayer else {return}
            audioPlayer!.delegate = self
        }
        audioPlayer?.play()
    } catch {
        print("Error in \(#function)\n" + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the background audio entitlement (capability) configured?

Comment: Not as far as I know of.

Comment: Well there you go then.

Comment: Yes it works. This is what was missing. Thanks!